# Dendrogram generated by scipy-cluster customisation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, dendrogram

This is a follow up to [Dendrogram generated by scipy-cluster does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2967858/188368).

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
from numpy.random import rand

X = rand( 5, 3 )
X[0:5, :] *= 2
Y = pdist( X )
Z = linkage( Y )
dendrogram( Z )
show()
```

when `dendrogram()` returns a dictionary with keys `ivl, leaves, color_list, icoord` that `pyplot` is picking up. How can I modify the labels and the leaf length before they are passed to `pyplot`?

Doing something like:

```
d=dendrogram( Z )
d['leaves']=['label1','label2','label3','label4','label5']
```

does not seem to affect it.

The leaf length should be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According the [dendrogram documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html), you should be able to define labels when you are calling it (either via **labels** or **leaf_label_func** args). So there is no need to try to tamper afterwards with labels.

Comment: `d = dendrogram( Z,labels=['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label5'] )` does the label trick